# Rings of fractions for all possible sets of denominators

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, fractions, localization

This is related to a question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2349912/complete-ring-of-fractions-of-mathbbz-n-for-any-n) except in this case, I am not asking about the total (complete) ring of fractions. **I am asking how to find all possible rings of fractions up to isomorphism for all possible denominators.**

Specifically, I am asking for the cases when the rings in question are

- $R = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$, where $p$ is a prime. (Note: This is NOT the p-adic integers. This is the set $\{0, 1, \cdots, p-1 \}$ of integers modulo a prime $p$.)
- $R=\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$, again, where $p$ is a prime.

I know that when $R = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$, which is a field, the only multiplicative subgroups are the zero subgroup, $U(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ (the units of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$), and of course $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ itself (although I don't know how to prove this).

When we are discussing the total ring of fractions, the set $D$ (sometimes called $S$) of denominators consists of all non-zero, non zero divisor elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. However, here, I am asked to consider ALL possible denominators. When $D$ contains $0$, what I get for my ring of fractions is the zero ring, correct (so this would also include the case when $D$ is the whole ring?)? When $D$ is the set of units, then I have the total ring of fractions, and I have, by the question I linked, that $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p}$? Is any of what I'm reasoning here correct?

But what about thee case when $R = \mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$? What are all the possible sets of denominators in this case? Recall that the set of denominators just has to be a sub-semigroup. So maybe even for the case where $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, I'm not including all the possible sets of denominators!

Please help, I am very confused. Thank you.

---

Where I'm getting stuck is - I don't know how to decide what all the $D$'s should be that I need to check. Because inversion by units doesn't change anything from the complete (total) ring of fractions, I suppose I should just consider $D$'s containing zero divisors and a $D$ consisting of just $0$ itself? Then, how do I figure out what they're isomorphic to?

Comment: @BillDubuque can you explain more? I need to consider all possible sets of divisors. So how do I know that I've considered them all? What are they?

Comment: You know that inverting units does nothing. So it remains to consider what happens when you invert the zero-divisors like $\,ap.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque do you get the zero ring when you do that? Because isn't that the case when 1=0, and so you have to have the zero ring?

Comment: Post your argument as an answer and we will give you feedback (or elaborate in your question where you get stuck).

Comment: $U(p)$ is a cyclic group of order $p - 1$. For example with $p = 5$ the group is isomorphic go $Z_4$ which has more than two subgroups. For instance $\{1,4\}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}/5$ with two elements.

Comment: @T.Gunn BillDubuque seems to be saying that it doesn't matter - comes out to the same thing except now I also need to consider the case for zero divisors.

Comment: @ALannister Did you cover inverting zero divisors?

Comment: @T.Gunn in detail? Not really. There was just a point where we glossed over what happens if zero occurs as a member of the set of denominators.

Comment: @ALannister The general theory is (for localizing at $S$) to set $\frac{x}{s} = \frac{x'}{s'}$ if there exists $r \in S$ such that $r(s'x - sx') = 0$. Does that look familiar? Then if $s \in S$ is a zero divisor and $sx = 0$ you have $\frac{x}{1} = \frac{0}{1}$ because $s(1 \cdot x - 1\cdot 0) = 0$.

Comment: @T.Gunn yes, I allude to that in my "answer" below. I made it community wiki, so please, feel free to edit.

Comment: @T.Gunn also, why is it called "localizing"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61829/discussion-between-t-gunn-and-alannister).

Comment: @T.Gunn I posted an answer finally. I'm still not sure how to explain in terms of $r(s^{\prime}x - sx^{\prime})=0$ how if $0 \in S$ (or what I call $D$), then $S^{-1}R$ is the zero ring. If you wouldn't mind posting the reason why either as a comment to my answer or as a separate answer, I would be so incredibly grateful. (If you posted it as a separate answer, I would accept your answer and not mine).

Comment: @T.Gunn I hate to bug you some more, but if you get a chance, can you take a look at another question I posted?: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2352954/showing-isomorphism-between-two-rings-of-fractions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $R = \mathbb{Z}_{p}$, $p$ prime:

> First, note that since $p$ is prime, $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a field;
>   i.e., $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ has no zero divisors. I.e., $\forall m \in
> \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ where $m \neq 0$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}$such
>   that $mn = nm = 1$ -i.e., every nonzero element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is
>   a unit.
>
> Now, suppose $D$ consists only of units, then $D \subseteq U(
>  \mathbb{Z}_{p})$. Also, note that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ has the identity. So, we apply the following result:

**Proposition** - Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $D$ be a nonempty multiplicative subsemigroup of $R$. Then the following is true:

1. The map $\phi: R \to D^{-1}R$ defined by 
   $$ \phi(x) = \frac{xy}{y}\, \text{for some}\,y \in D. $$
   is a ring homomorphism.
2. If $0 \notin D$ and $D$ has no zero divisors, then $\phi$ is a monomorphism.
3. The image $\phi(x)$ of every element $x \in D$ is invertible; i.e., $\phi (D) \subseteq U(D^{-1}R)$.
4. If $R$ has the identity and $D \subseteq U(R)$ then $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

> to conclude that the map $\displaystyle \phi: \mathbb{Z}_{p}\to D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ defined by $\displaystyle \phi(x) = \frac{xy}{y}$ for some $y \in D$ is an isomorphism. **Thus, in the case when $D$ consists only of units, the ring of fractions is $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_{p}$.**
>
> Second, suppose instead that $0 \in D$. In order for the pairs $(x,y)$, $(x^{\prime},y^{\prime}) \in R \times D$ to be equal, there must exist some $z \in D$ such that 
>   $$ (xy^{\prime}-yx^{\prime})z = 0.$$
>
> Now, according to my notes, this guarantees that $D^{-1}R$ must be the
>   zero ring, but I am not sure why in terms of $(xy^{\prime} -
> yx^{\prime})z=0$ that is true. **If someone could explain that to me
>   either in the comments or in a different answer, I would be most
>   appreciative.**
>
> **So, to summarize, in the case that $0 \in D$, $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p} =
>  \{0\}$.**

- $R = \mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$, $p$ prime:

> In the case that $R = \mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$, the set of units is the set
>   of all $m \in \mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$ such that $\gcd(m, p^{2}) = 1$.
>
> So, suppose first that $D$ consists only of units of
>   $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$. Then, $D \subseteq U(\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}})$, and
>   we note that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$ has the identity. Therefore, by the
>   proposition given in the first bullet point, the map $\phi:
> \mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}} \to D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$ defined by
>   $\displaystyle \phi(x)=\frac{xy}{y}$ for some $y \in D$ is an
>   isomorphism. Thus, **in the case when $D$ consists only of units, the
>   ring of fractions is $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}} \simeq
> \mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$.**
>
> **Second, suppose that $0 \in D$.** By the remarks in the first bullet
>   point, again, **this is the case where $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$ is the
>   zero ring.**
>
> Third, suppose that $D$ contains a zero divisor. Now, zero divisors of
>   $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$ are multiples of $p$.
>
> Since $D$ is a multiplicative semisubgroup, if $ap \in D$ where $ap$
>   is a multiple of $p$, then $D$ contains $(ap)\cdot (ap) = (ap)^{2} =
> a^{2}p^{2} = a^{2} \cdot 0 = 0$.
>
> So, if $D$ contains a zero divisor, it also contains $0$ itself, which
>   degenerates to the case where $0 \in D$; i.e., in this case also,
>   $D^{-1}\mathbb{Z}_{p^{2}}$ is the zero ring.

Comment: I will use slightly different letters to make clear which elements belong to $D$. We have $\frac{x_1}{s_1} = \frac{x_2}{s_2}$ if and only if there exists $r \in D$ such that $r(s_2x_1 - s_1x_2) = 0$. If I am allowed to take $r = 0$ then I have $0(s_2x_1 - s_1x_2) = 0$. This is always true regardless of what $x_1,x_2,s_1,s_2$ are. Thus all fractions in $D^{-1}R$ are equal. If you have a ring where every two elements are equal then that ring is the zero ring.

Comment: The rest of your answer reflects a good understanding of the problem.

Comment: @T.Gunn thank you for everything!